# Azure Data Factory - Setting up variables for Cosmos DB

Tags: etl, azure-data-factory

I am using dataflow to insert data into Cosmos DB. My dataflow is linked to two Cosmos databases and I want to specify a variable to insert data into one Cosmos DB at a time when I trigger the pipeline. Whats the best way to do that?

Comment: If the answer was helpful , You can [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), ( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Answer (score 0):

You can have **a parameterized Cosmos linked service connection at sink dataset**, this will prompt to input value to the parameter when pipeline is triggered. Here you can manually enter value at pipeline trigger prompt or set value to a variable dynamically or default and execute the pipeline.

### Example:

**Edit linked service:**

[image]

**Set CosmosDB name property to a parameter:**

[image]

**Create a Dataset parameter and assign it to linked service parameter:**

[image]

[image]

**Now...in pipeline**

[image]

### OR

[image]

### OR

[image]

[image]